# Setting up ImageMagick + Imagick for PHP for use with AMPPS on Mac OSX 10.9.5

Tags: php, macos, imagemagick, imagick, ampps

I have been searching the internet for hours and I am pulling my hair out. I cannot for the life of me work out why I cannot configure Imagick for use by PHP within my local AMPPS development environment.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

I am on Mac OSX 10.9.5. As far as I am aware Imagemagick is installed on my machine. I cannot find out how to configure Imagick for use by AMPPS.

I have got as far as the message below in my AMPPS Apache error log:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.3/lib/extensions/ext/imagick.so' - dlopen(/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.3/lib/extensions/ext/imagick.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

I have tried copying the installed 'imagick.so' file to the directory specified in the error above. To which I have the imagick.so extension ticked in the extensions tab.

But then when I go to use Imagick (i.e $image = new Imagick->($src))

I get...

Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found

Any ideas. I'm at the end of my tether with this. Thanks guys.

Comment: You really ought to use Vagrant and then develop in a Linux environment. Trying to get stuff working on OSX is probably not a good use of your time.

Comment: Hi Danack, Firstly thanks, it is potentially something to look at doing in the future. But for now I have been running this development environment for over a year with no issues. I just need to have Imagick working within AMPPS. Would you be able to give me any advice on this matter?

Comment: #Danack. In any way why is that a relevant comment for Joseppi's question? Lol :P